# identifying files matching *.X where no *.X.Y exists using find

Tags: bash

I have a directory with .tif files and I usually use the `find` command to identify these files

```
find . -name '*.tif'
```

I now have a mixture of .tif and .tif.mrc files. The file names are identical except for the extensions (`file1.tif` and `file1.tif.mrc`). I only want to identify the `.tif` files that do not have corresponding `.tif.mrc` files. Can I do this using the `find` command?

Comment: Hmm. I'm almost certain we have a dupe for this...

Comment: Ahh -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685790/how-to-find-all-files-that-dont-have-a-matching-file-with-the-same-name-but-diff is our dupe. Unfortunately, the answers it has are *awful* -- all three we have here so far are better.

Comment: The one difference between this question and that, @CharlesDuffy, is that the other looks for `*.tif.mrc` files without a matching `*.tif` file as well as the converse (whereas this question only asks about `*.tif` files without a matching `*.tif.mrc` file).  I'm think we could count that as enough difference not to need to use this one as a duplicate of that.

Comment: find . -name "*.tif" should show you only the .tif files

Answer (score 3):

The `test` (aka `[`)  utility has a bunch of general purpose tests, such as checking whether a file exists. You can run that as part of your `find` condition with `-exec`:

```
find . -name '*.tif' ! -exec test -e "{}.mrc" \; -print
```

Comment: This is a much cleaner answer than what I was thinking of, +1 for `test`.

Answer (score 2):

Consider running one shell command for a group of files, rather once per file as in [that other guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1899640/that-other-guy)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46656409/).

For example:

```
find . -name '*.tif' -exec sh -c \
    'for file in "$@"; do [ -f "$file.mrc" ] || echo "$file"; done' \
    harbinger-of-doom {} +
```

The code runs `sh -c '…' harbinger-of-doom` plus a string of one or more file names that will fit.  The name `harbinger-of-doom` is the '`$0`' for the script run by `sh -c`; choose any sensible (or not sensible) name that you like.  The `{}` specifies where the file names should be put; the `+` indicates that `find` should group conveniently large numbers of file names into a single execution.

The actual script is:

```
for file in "$@"; do [ -f "$file.mrc" ] || echo "$file"; done
```

For each filename argument, test whether the file name with the `.mrc` extension exists, and if not, print the file name.  If you want null terminated file names (as with `find … -print0`), replace `echo` with `printf "%s\0"`.  This uses the built-in `[` (test) command and built-in `echo` (or `printf`) command, so it doesn't invoke any subshells.  Whether this actually matters is somewhat debatable; the performance difference will not be huge, but it could be significant if you have hundreds or thousands of files to test.  You can also tune the file test — does the file exist (`-e`), or is it readable `-r`, or is it writable (`-w`), or not empty (`-s`), or …

This solution is comparable to, and effectively equivalent to, [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46656519/).  This has the advantage of working if your shell does not support [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution), but current versions of Bash do support it, so that's not directly relevant.  It does mean that older shells, or more strictly POSIX-compliant shells like Dash, could run this version.

Answer (score 2):

i'm not sure how many files you have, but i once had to do this for a very large number of files, and came up with a much more efficient way. (i was reminded of this by Jonathan Leffer's answer):

```
find . -name '*.tif' -printf '[ -e %f.mrc ] || echo %f\n' | sh
```

this creates a bunch of command strings to test for each `.tif` whether it has an `.mrc`, e.g.,:

```
[ -e file1.tif.mrc ] || echo file1.tif
[ -e foal.tif.mrc ] || echo foal.tif
[ -e fum.tif.mrc ] || echo fum.tif
...
```

and pipes these tests directly to just a single execution of `sh`, which is why it is ~100x as fast as that other guy's answer.

benchmarks:

```
me               -printf | sh      400k files/second
Jonathan Leffer  -exec sh -c {} +  220k files/second
Charles Duffy    bash test          50k files/second
that other guy   -exec test          3k files/second
```

additionally, if you want to use this to perform a specific `<command>` on the tifs with no mrcs, do:

```
find . -name '*.tif' -printf '[ -e %f.mrc ] || <command> %f\n' | sh
```

or, slower but perhaps more easily understandable (?):

```
find . -name '*.tif' -printf '[ -e %f.mrc ] || echo %f\n' | sh |
  while read tifpath; do
    echo "$tifpath has no .mrc"
    <command> $tifpath
  done
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, avoiding the need to invoke `/bin/test` for each file (and the performance hit associated therewith):

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
  test -e "${filename}.mrc" || printf '%q\n' "$filename"
done < <(find . -name '*.tif' -print0)
```

This is a bit longer, but more efficient since it's able to use the shell-builtin version of `test` (and can reuse the shell you already have, instead of needing to start one or more new ones).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the suggestions. I'm trying each one out now. A colleague also suggested the following that seems to work

## find all files with .tif extension

x=$(find . -name '*.tif')

for i in $x; do

## if the file $x.mrc exists, then skip it

if [[ -f $i.mrc ]] ;
then
echo skipping "$i";
else
echo "processing $i" ;

fi
done

However this doesn't work for another set of files with slightly different extension, namely _LA.mrc. Using if [[ -f $i_LA.mrc ]] ; doesn't work

Comment: try `[[ -f "$i"_LA.mrc ]]`, otherwise `bash` interprets `i_LA` is the variable name.